# Windows Forms app on mobile scanner, can't scan to textbox

Tags: winforms, mobile, barcode-scanner

Having some issues with setting up simple textbox on the windows form on my scanner.
I have to add new textbox to existing already created app, and my new textbox doesn't seem to work.

When i set focus to my textbox, then i try to scan a barcode, no data is displayed in the textbox. I can scan barcode into already created textbox in the app just fine, can't figure out whats the diference.

I don't see any difference in properties of two textboxes, same everything.

Please advise

Comment: You are not clear in your question. Please elaborate and / or share some sample to explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that your scanner read event handlers are attached to the existing textbox. You'd have to add this same handler to your new textbox.